# SCORM from chamilo Platform

Tags: php, django, cookies, chamilo-lms

I´m developing and e-learning platform in Django based on Chamilo LMS services and databases. Currently I´m facing a problem with course content because of cookies (I think is that). The data extracting using the api is used to fill an url with parameters to be passed on PHP file but in the iFrame nothing is shown, only shows a login form.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Chamilo? version 1.11.14?
You can activate the Scorm logs in the scorm_api.php file.
The problem can also be your Scorm content.
Try to create simple content with Open eLearning software that is compatible with Chamilo LMS (and Moodle).

Comment: Currently It's use the version 1.11.x(for develop it's use the 1.11.10 but for final product will be 1.11.14)